# Material-UI(React): Access theme with StyledComponents and TypeScript causes in Type-Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I just tried to access the theme in own of my styled components like:

```
const ToolbarPlaceholder = styled('div')((theme: any) => ({
   minHeight: theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeight,
}));
```

I got this from the docu: https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#styled-components-api-15-lines- (at the end of the page)

But I get following Type-Error:

```
Argument of type '(theme: any) => { minHeight: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray'.
  Property 'raw' is missing in type '(theme: any) => { minHeight: any; }'.
```

What is missing? And which type does the `theme` param have?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use the [`styled-components` type definitions](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript) with the "styled-components API" example from Material-UI?  While they look similar, these are two different projects and they work incompatibly; `styled-components` uses a template string literal and Material-UI uses an object literal.  Choose one or the other.  (The [Material-UI example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/047dab5064ae971e23a318bdd609077eef6d6efa/docs/src/pages/customization/css-in-js/StyledComponents.js#L9-L23) is defined in JavaScript without type annotations, but you could use it untyped.  The type of the `theme` parameter is just `Theme` from `@material-ui/core`.)